# Unable to get handle using int 21h 3Dh

Tags: assembly, masm

I'm using the DOSBOX0.74 to learn 16-bit assembly.

Below is my code：

```
DATAS SEGMENT
    filehandle dw 0
    filename db 'target.txt',0
    err db "can't open$"
    readbuffer db 256 dup(0)
    write   db 64
            db ?
            db 64 dup(0)


CODES SEGMENT
    ASSUME CS:CODES,DS:DATAS

START:
    MOV AX,DATAS
    MOV DS,AX
    
    mov ax, 3d02h
    lea dx,filename
    int 21h
    jc error
    jmp isend
error:
    mov ah,9
    mov dx,offset err
    int 21h
isend:
    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H
CODES ENDS
    END START
```

when I run it, my error message displayed.
And I also using debug try to find what went wrong.The results seems to be due to Permission denied,because I got **0x05 in ax**.

And then I tried the following methods to try to solve this problem:

1.Run DOSBOX as administrator.

2.Set the permissions of target.txt to full control.

3.Set al to 0x00,using only read to open the file.

But none of these methods work,ax is still return error code with 0x05.I searched this site for similar problems but I didn't find any solutions that worked for me,So please forgive me for re-posing the question,thinks.
[image]

Comment: Please do not run Dosbox as the administrator.  This is not needed to make your code work and may just make things worse.  You can hose your system by running bad programs with elevated privileges.

Comment: I would check if `target.txt` is not opened by something else in nonsharing mode.

Comment: Probably unrelated to the error, but you can use the P command to Debug when it has disassembled the `int 21` instruction. This will proceed past the interrupt call rather than trace into the handler.

Comment: And while I do believe that your error message is shown, the screenshot doesn't establish that you get an error 5. It could be the process handle number 5 that was opened. It depends on whether the `iret` sets or clears the Carry Flag, which isn't apparent from your screenshot.

Comment: @ecm You're right. When I used 5 for read and write operations, it worked fine. I initially thought the handle would be a much larger number, so I kept thinking it was just an error code. That's a real joke.